# C++11 auto iterator type with std::begin(), std::end() issue

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have some private class member, representing random access array of `std::deque` containing some data:

```
std::vector<std::deque<SomeDataClass> > someMember;
```

I would like to provide a public class method which returns iterable data structure, containing all data elements from my array of deques:

```
std::deque<SomeDataClass> someMethod();
```

I would like this method go through all the deques in vector and copy every element on it's way to local std::deque, eventually returning this local std::deque by value.
I'm trying to implement this method using C++11 `auto` and `std::begin()`, `std::end()`:

```
std::deque<SomeDataClass> MyClassName::someMethod(){
    std::deque<DirectedEdge> allDataItems;
    std::deque<DirectedEdge>::iterator deqIter = allDataItems.begin();
    for(auto it = std::begin(someMember); it != std::end(someMember); ++it){
        std::copy(std::begin(*it), std::end(*it), deqIter);
    }

    return allDataItems;
}
```

I receive data access violation unhandled exception error on runtime in deque header. What is a mistake?

Comment: You should always use `!=` for the ending condition when using iterators. Nothing says the next one is further ahead in memory.

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks. I'll edit my question, stupid mistake. I still have access violation.

Comment: @chris: Nothing says so apart from the standard, as long as the container is a vector. And anyway, for random access iterators, `operator<` does not tell you the order in memory, but the order in the logical sequence (for other iterator categories, it isn't defined at all). Since the only containers used in vard's code are vector and deque, which both have random access iterators, using `operator<` on them is perfectly fine (as long as both iterators belong to the same container, of course).

Comment: @celtschk, I knew someone would comment on that. Yes, random-access iterators will work fine with `operator<`, but I value being able to change something without breaking everything else. Using `operator!=` works with every iterator type. I should have made it a bit more clear, but my five minutes was up by the time I thought about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::copy()` requires the destination range to be large enough to hold the copy, but `allDataItems` is empty. You'd have to reserve space in `allDataItems` in advance (but that's not possible with `std::deque`). You should use a `std::back_inserter` (defined in `<iterator>`) instead:

```
std::deque<SomeDataClass> MyClassName::someMethod(){
    std::deque<DirectedEdge> allDataItems;
    for(auto it = std::begin(someMember); it < std::end(someMember); ++it){
        std::copy(std::begin(*it), std::end(*it), std::back_inserter(allDataItems));
    }

    return allDataItems;
}
```

Comment: Consider doing `allDataItems.insert(std::end(allDataItems), ...);` instead. I'd say it's usually better to use members when possible.

Comment: @chris You can make that a separate answer, so the OP can decide which they like better.

Comment: Just add it to yours and then there's an even better answer :)

Comment: `!=` works instead of `<` and means that if `someMember` wasn't a random-access container, the code would still work.  And if you don't need the iterator, `for( auto const& x : someMember )` is clearer and shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idomatic C+11 way to do it:

```
std::deque<SomeDataClass> MyClassName::someMethod() {
  std::deque<DirectedEdge> allDataItems;

  for( auto const& dq : someMember ) {
    allDataItems.insert( allDataItems.end(), std::begin(dq), std::end(dq) );
  }
  return allDataItems;
}
```

another way would be to write a `concatinate` function:

```
struct concatenate {
  template<typename Dest, typename Src>
  Dest&& operator()( Dest&& d, Src const& s ) const {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    typename std::decay<Dest>::type retval = std::forward<Dest>(d);
    retval.insert( end(retval), begin(s), end(s) );
    return std::move(retval);
  }
};
std::deque<SomeDataClass> MyClassName::someMethod() {
  using std::begin; using std::end; // enable ADL
  return std::accumulate(
    begin(someMember), end(someMember),
    std::deque<DirectedEdge>(), concatenate()
  );
}
```

which is pretty cute.  If you don't like `std::accumulate`,

```
std::deque<SomeDataClass> MyClassName::someMethod() {
  std::deque<DirectedEdge> allDataItems;

  for( auto const& dq : someMember ) {
    allDataItems = concatenate( std::move(allDataItems), dq );
  }
  return allDataItems;
}
```

both of which are roughly equivalently efficient.

Comment: @benvoigt renamed function to `merriam_webster` as requested.